# Laravel build an array from query results

Tags: php, laravel

here are some objects which i fetch from query results

```
{
    {
        "name": "John",
        "notification": "sms"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "notification": "email"
    },
}
```

From those results, i want to build an array like this

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "notification":['email', 'sms']
}
```

Anyone who can light up my day?

Comment: The source is an array of objects? The name is unique or you can have different names in same array?

Comment: @fusion3k ("name","notification") is unique

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original *object* is an array of objects, if you want a single object as result, you can do this (`$data` is your original array):

```
$result = (object) [ 'name' => $data[0]->name, 'notifications' => [] ];
foreach( $data as $item ) $result->notifications[] = $item->notification;
```

On php 7, you can also do this:

```
$result = (object) [ 'name' => $data[0]->name, 'notifications' => array_column( $data, 'notification' ) ];
```

Both examples have this result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => John
    [notifications] => Array
        (
            [0] => sms
            [1] => email
        )

)
```

Or, wiht JSON syntax:

```
{"name":"John","notifications":["sms","email"]}
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/556230)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @fusion3k, this answer is very helpful for me, you save my day